# android get last 5 records

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to get the latest 5 records in my table, so far i tried this but, it did not work out very well. So, what is the cleanest and efficient way to get last 5 records in the table ?

```
"select * from (select * from People order by Date DESC limit 5) order by Date ASC;"
```

Comment: `(select * from People order by Date DESC limit 5)` this is not a table right?

Comment: no, i look for a method using id instead Date... but not sure which one is efficient if you consider a big table over 10000 records

Answer (score 0):

Your query works just fine.

To make it efficient, ensure that there is an index on the `Date` column; then SQLite will just read the last five entries from the index and the table and does not need to scan the entire table.

If this table has an autoincrementing ID column, and if "latest" means the insertion order, then you can use that ID for sorting; this will be as efficient as your original query with an index on `Date`:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM People
               ORDER BY _id DESC
               LIMIT 5)
ORDER BY Date ASC
```